# Show the following is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ which is no square and $\alpha = \frac{1+\sqrt{m}}{2} \in \mathbb{C}$. For which $m$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] = \{a + b \alpha \ | \ a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ a subring.

All of the following properties are obvious:

$\bullet \ 1 \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \\ \bullet \ 0 \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \\ \bullet \ x-y \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$

But then I started with the property that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \rightarrow x \cdot y \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. Which did not work for me yet.

What I tried:
say $x = (a+b \alpha), y = (c + d \alpha) \\ x \cdot y = ac + (ad + bc)\alpha + bd\alpha^2$

I have to show that $bd\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $bd\alpha^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$bd\alpha = \frac{bd + bd\sqrt{m}}{2} \ \ \ bd\alpha^2 = \frac{bd+2bd\sqrt{m}+m}{4}$

How can I show that one of those two are elements in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: When we write $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$, that _usually_ means the collection of _all polynomials_ with coefficients in $\Bbb Z$ and variable $\alpha$, not just the first degree polynomials (and as such it will basically automatically be closed under multiplication). It's fine to go against conventional notation since you explicitly define what the notation means in this specific context, but just be careful when you encounter such notation again that it won't necessarily mean the same.

Comment: It turns out my answer was wrong, and I don't really have time to correct it right now. But I still recommend you try the same approach: Set $a=c=0$ and $b=d=0$ and look for the $m$ which allow $\alpha^2\in\Bbb Z[\alpha]$. It's easier than the general case, and once you have that, it is rather easy to prove that $\alpha^2\in\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ implies that $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Despite your answer was not correct, you still helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with $a = c = 0, b = d = 1$, just to make things easier. Is $\alpha^2\in \Bbb Z[\alpha]$?

We have
$$
\alpha^2 = \frac{1 + 2\sqrt m + m}{4} = \frac{1+m}4 + \frac{\sqrt m}2
$$
and we want this to be $a + b\alpha$ for some $a, b\in \Bbb Z$:
$$
a + b\alpha = a + \frac b2 + \frac{b\sqrt m}2 = \frac{1+m}4 + \frac{\sqrt m}2
$$
Clearly we must have $b = 1$. This forces
$$
a + \frac 12 = \frac{1+m}4\\
a = \frac{m-1}{4}
$$
which means that $\alpha^2\in\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ iff $m-1$ is divisible by $4$.

And if $\alpha^2\in \Bbb Z[\alpha]$, then $$(a+b\alpha)(c+d\alpha) = ac + (ad + bc)\alpha + bd\alpha^2\in \Bbb Z[\alpha]$$

So as long as $m-1$ is divisible by $4$, $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ is closed under multiplication and thus a subring of $\Bbb C$.

Note that neither $bd\alpha\in \Bbb Z$ or $bd\alpha^2\in \Bbb Z$ is required.

Comment: How is $\alpha^2 \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$? Which $b$ do I need to choose to receive $\frac{\frac{1+m}{2}+\sqrt{m}}{2}$?

Comment: @Paul I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here $bd\alpha\in{\Bbb Z}[\alpha]$ as $b,d\in{\Bbb Z}$.

But generally $bd\alpha^2\not\in{\Bbb Z}[\alpha]$ since $\alpha^2=\frac{1}{4}(1+\sqrt m)^2 = \frac{1}{4}(1+m + 2\sqrt m)$ and $\frac{1}{4}\not\in{\Bbb Z}[\alpha]$.

Comment: Okay, one has to search for the ''correct'' $m$'s.

Comment: The question is "For which $m$ is ...", so yes, searching for the "correct" $m$ is exactly what we are asked to do. I just realized that I misread / misunderstood some things in the question, so my previous comment (and my answer) didn't apply as well as I thought. But still. Yes, that is what one has to do.